# Faking decimal with string format

Tags: c#, string, format, string-formatting

I currently have the following longs in a small C# program.

```
long one = 1;
long two = 1005;
long three = 100000005;
long four = 1111112258552;
```

I want to format them in a string so that they are a thousandth of the size without dividing the values by a thousand.

Example

```
Input               :               Output
1                                    0.001
1005                                 1.005
100000005                       100000.005
1111112258552               1111112258.552
```

I have tried string formats such as `{0:0,000}` and `{0:0.000}` but neither provided the result I was after.

How can I achieve the result I am after? Any tips or pointers would be appreciated

---

Some sample code

```
long one = 1;
long two = 1005;
long three = 100000005;
long four = 1111112258552;

string format = "{0:0,000}";
string s1 = String.Format(format, one);
string s2 = String.Format(format, two);
string s3 = String.Format(format, three);
string s4 = String.Format(format, four);

Console.WriteLine(s1);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
Console.WriteLine(s3);
Console.WriteLine(s4);
```

Comment: *"I want to format them in a string so that they are a thousandth of the size without dividing the values by a thousand."* -- **Why?** *"How can I achieve the result I am after?"* -- **divide the values by 1000.0**.

Comment: What is wrong with (one/1000).ToString();  ?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Purely because I am interested in how it could be achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "{0:0,.000}" for your format.

```
long one = 1;
long two = 1005;
long three = 100000005;
long four = 1111112258552;
string format = "{0:0,.000}";
string s1 = String.Format(format, one);
string s2 = String.Format(format, two);
string s3 = String.Format(format, three);
string s4 = String.Format(format, four);

Console.WriteLine(s1);
Console.WriteLine(s2);
Console.WriteLine(s3);
Console.WriteLine(s4);
```

Console output:

```
0.001
1.005
100000.005
1111112258.552
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-2

Comment: That was precisely what I was after. Thank you